# SEO solution for microblogs?

Tags: seo, microblogging

we all have heard about benefits of microblogs but what if we have a microblog and want to boost it's SEO?

the biggest problem in microblogs is keywords are not related to each other and each topic has a small amount of related keywords.

for example if we have a microblog that has short tips about all fields in computer sience, and a blog that publish articles in this field too.

the outlined blog has a better chance to be appeared in SERP, instead the underlined microblog has no chance because of it's limited keywords.

am i right and what is the SEO solution for these microblogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, blog with more keywords can rank better than microblog with few keywords because there is more content on blog.

For many seo addicts, content is king! No matter support of website, the most important is having always more content (and thus keywords).

In my opinion, blog is more powerful in seo than microblog.